# Python method changing all key value pairs in dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I am in the process of building a little python script that learns to play tic tac toe.  My process is to store each move made in a game and score that move based on whether it lead to a winning outcome.  Eventually I will attempt to train this on many rounds of play.

**My problem lies with my `update_weights()` method**.  I expect it to take the stored moves (accessed from the board object and represented as a list [row,col]) and iterate through that list of moves.  The method should then reference the board's stored weights (a dictionary of (3,3) numpy arrays) and update the corresponding weight for the appropriate move.

e.g. Assume a win occurred. In the winning sequence move #2 was at board position [0,1]. The method should access the dictionary of weights (keys are the move #) and multiply the position of the array [0,1] by a factor of 1.05.

**The problem is that my method is changing ALL the arrays in my weight dictionary**, not just the one associated with the correct move # key.  I can't figure out how this is happening.

```
import numpy as np
import random

    class ttt_board():

        def __init__(self):
            self.board_state = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
            self.board_weight = self.reset_board_weights()
            self.moves = []

        def reset_board_weights(self):
            board_weight_instance = np.zeros((3,3))
            board_weight_instance[board_weight_instance >= 0] = 0.5

            board_weight = {0: board_weight_instance,
                            1: board_weight_instance,
                            2: board_weight_instance,
                            3: board_weight_instance,
                            4: board_weight_instance}

            return board_weight

        def reset_board(self):
            self.board_state = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])

        def reset_moves(self):
            self.moves = []

        def is_win(self):
            board = self.board_state 
            if board.trace() == 3 or np.flipud(board).trace() == 3:
                return True
            for i in range(3):
                if board.sum(axis=0)[i] == 3 or board.sum(axis=1)[i] == 3:
                    return True
            else:
                return False

        def is_loss(self):
            board = self.board_state 
            if board.trace() == 12 or np.flipud(board).trace() == 12:
                return True
            for i in range(3):
                if board.sum(axis=0)[i] == 12 or board.sum(axis=1)[i] == 12:
                    return True
            else:
                return False

        def is_tie(self):
            board = self.board_state
            board_full = True
            for i in range(len(board)):
                for k in range(len(board)):
                    if board[i][k] == 0:
                        board_full = False
            if board_full and  not self.is_win() and not self.is_loss():
                return True
            else:
                return False

        def update_board(self,player,space):
            #takes player as 1 or 4
            #takes space as list [0,0]
            self.board_state[space[0],space[1]] = player

            if player == 1:
                self.store_move(space)
            return

        def get_avail_spots(self):
            avail_spots = []
            board = self.board_state
            for i in range(len(board)):
                for k in range(len(board)):
                    if board[i][k] == 0:
                        avail_spots.append([i,k])
            return avail_spots

        def gen_next_move(self):
            avail_spots = self.get_avail_spots()
            move = random.randrange(len(avail_spots))
            return avail_spots[move]

        def update_weights(self,win):
            moves = self.moves
            if win:
                factor = 1.05
            else:
                factor= 0.95
            for i in range(len(moves)):
                row = moves[i][0]
                col = moves[i][1]
                old_weight = self.board_weight[i][row,col]
                new_weight = old_weight*factor
                self.board_weight[i][row,col] = new_weight
            return

        def store_move(self,move):
            self.moves.append(move)
            return


    if __name__ == '__main__':

        board = ttt_board()

        while not board.is_win() and not board.is_loss() and not board.is_tie():
            try:
                board.update_board(1,board.gen_next_move())
                board.update_board(4,board.gen_next_move())
            except ValueError:
                break

        if board.is_win():
            board.update_weights(1)
            print('Player 1 wins: {w}'.format(w=board.is_win()))
        elif board.is_loss():
            board.update_weights(0)
            print('Player 2 wins: {l}'.format(l=board.is_loss()))
        elif board.is_tie():
            print('Game ends in tie: {t}'.format(t=board.is_tie()))

        print('Here is the final board')
        print(board.board_state)
        print(board.board_weight)
        print(board.moves)
```

As you can see by running the script, the printed dictionary of weights after a single game has identical array values for each key.  **I would expect each array to only be changed in one position as it should only be accessed for the move # corresponding to the key it is associated with.**

Comment: It's difficult to read so much code generally http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Not really related, but using `numpy` arrays like this is probably going to give you worse performance than plain python lists.

Comment: @martianwars thanks for the heads up. I'll isolate the issue in less code and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you share the same reference on your `board_weight_instance` array in the dictionary

```
board_weight_instance = np.zeros((3,3))
board_weight_instance[board_weight_instance >= 0] = 0.5

board_weight = {0: board_weight_instance,
                1: board_weight_instance,
                2: board_weight_instance,
                3: board_weight_instance,
                4: board_weight_instance}
```

I would do this in a dictionary comprehension, creating a new reference for each element using a helper method:

```
@staticmethod
def create_element():
   board_weight_instance = np.zeros((3,3))
   board_weight_instance[:] = 0.5  # simpler than your method
   return board_weight_instance

board_weight = {i:self.create_element() for i in range(0,5)}
```

in your case, why even using a dictionary when you can use a `list`: no hashing, faster processing:

```
board_weight = [self.create_element() for _ in range(0,5)]
```

you can access it the same way